# Wordpress Rewrite: Ignore Specific Pattern

Tags: url-rewriting

I want to make Wordpress Rewrite to ignore a specific pattern, here is what I mean:

I have this lovely page

```
http://mysite.com/my-lovely-page
```

I want to ignore anything that contains the word "section" and comes after "my-lovely-page" to be ignored, for example this would be ignored:

```
http://mysite.com/my-lovely-page/section/about
```

By Ignored, I mean that Wordpress would return the same content as for "my-lovely-page".

Is there a safe way to do it without directly modifying .htaccess ?

Comment: Can I ask why? What are you doing with this page?

Comment: I have sub-sections that I want to be linkable with html5 push state instead of the regular hashtags on modern browsers. Basically it's a linkable accordion.

Comment: Have you looked into [endpoints](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint)?

Comment: No, but that looks exactly like what I need. Thanks!